# Google Guice: Mock a @provides method consists of set of object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, guice

I have class A which is taking a set as guice dependency. The set is singleton. Below is the code example:

```
class A
{
   private Set<InetAddress> set;
   private String pingUriPath;
   @Inject
   public A(Set<InetAddress> set, @Named("pingUri") String pingUriPath)
        {
          this.set = set;
          this.pingUriPath = pingUriPath; // this is used somewhere
        }

   public void storeValue(String str)
   {
      if(str.equals("abc"))
       {
          set.add(str);
       }
   }

}
```

Here is the guice module that injects dependency:

```
private class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
          bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("pingUri")).to("/ping");
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        Set<InetAddress> healthyTargets(){
            return Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
        }
    }
```

I want to mock the method storeValue and for that i have to mock the set. I am not able to mock the set using guice.
If i mock like below, it gives assertion error(no interactions with this mock)

```
@Mock
Set<InetAddress> mockHealthyTargets;

private class MockClassesModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("pingUri")).to("/ping");
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        Set<InetAddress> healthyTargets(){
            return Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
        }
    }

public test_storeValue()
{
   Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MockClassesModule());
   A a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
   a.storeValue("abc");
   verify(mockHealthyTargets).add("abc")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the need to use guice in your unit tests, something is most likely going the wrong direction. One of the biggest benefits of dependency injection is that testing becomes easy, because you can pass dependencies that are controlled by you.

I assume you want to test the class A and specifically the method storeValue. For this you don't even need mocking

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // prepare dependencies
    Set<InetAddress> set = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet(); 
    String pingUri = "example.com";

    // prepare input
    String input = "someValue";

    // prepare class under test
    A classUnderTest = new A(set, pingUri);

    // call class under test
    classUnderTest.storeValue(input);

    // check that what you expected happened
    // in this case you expect that the dependency set now contains the input
    assertThat(set, contains(input));
}
```

Comment: Using a DI framework in your **unit** tests indicates that something is going in the wrong direction. Using a DI framework in your **integration** tests seems OK to me

Answer (score 0):

I have found what the mistake was, I should return mock when providing to my unit test. It should look like this:

```
@Mock
Set<InetAddress> mockHealthyTargets;

private class MockClassesModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("pingUri")).to("/ping");
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        Set<InetAddress> healthyTargets(){
            return mockHealthyTargets;
        }
    }
```